# Display text in a div only when a CSS transition kicks in?

Tags: css

I have the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zf5am/579/

I'm trying to display the text only when the hover effect (transparency) kicks in.  The text should be full-opacity, very readable, but only on hover, on top of the opaque image.  Can this be done using only CSS?

```css
.image img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.image {
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
}

.text {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img class="fade" src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="text">TEST</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try setting text color to transparent by default and give it a color on hover, also put text before image in the html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of triggering on the hover of the child element, use nested selectors to trigger on the hover of the containing element:

```
div:hover .fade {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
div:hover .text{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This is the only way it can work since otherwise the elements are obscuring eachother, thus they are not both getting a `:hover` behaviour themselves. The parent does though, allowing you to select its children.

[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/Zf5am/581/).

Comment: Thanks Niels.  I coped and pasted this line for line into my solution but the images are always showing up as solid black unless I hover, then the opacity kicks in.  My text is below the image in markup, just like in the fiddle.  Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: I don't have a crystal ball to look into your solution, but the obvious answer is that 'something else in your CSS' is interfering. As you can see from the Fiddle the clean self-contained example works fine.